# How can I access Windows File Share with Flutter Android?

Tags: flutter

I need to connect to the Windows File Share and open files. I searched the internet but couldn't find any documentation. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have a code to write anyway I'm looking for code I can write